# Dart double issue

Tags: flutter, dart

dart cant change 14.99942 to 14.99; toStringAsFixed() doesn't work properly.
Example:

(179.99 / 12.00).toStringAsFixed(2)

expected result: 14.99

actual result: 15.00

Comment: Did you try with (179.99 / 12.00).toStringAsFixed(3)? Then you will get 14.999. toStringAsFixed() is rounding.

Comment: I don't want to get 14.999, I only need two numbers after decimal: 14.99

Comment: seems like it is round up the number

Answer (score 0):

A possible workaround is to define your own method.

```
String toFixedString(double nr){
  String n=nr.toString();
  final pos=n.indexOf('.');
  return n.substring(0,pos+3);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with this Extension

```dart
extension NumberExtension on num {
  String toStringAsFixedWithoutRound(int n) {
    final r = toString().split(".");
    return "${r.first}.${r.last.substring(0, n)}";
  }
}
```